# force an opportunity to always have the same contract

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

Currently our salesforce users are changing the contracts of the opportunities. We automatically create a contract and do some maintenance on the contracts so we do not want anyone to replace the contracts.

My approach is to create a new field called ContractId__c, I will use this new field along with a trigger to make sure that any update in the contract field must have the same contract id.

Is there any other easy and better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a trigger for this use.

You should write a validation rule like this to check the prior value and current value:

```
NOT($Permission.Change_Contract_Permission) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(Contract_Id__c)) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Contract_Id__c)))
&& ISChanged(Contract_Id__c) 
&& PRIORVALUE(Contract_Id__c) != Contract_Id__c
```

then throw an error message

You can also create  [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_create.htm&type=5) and assign this to users who wants to change the contract. In the above example `Change_Contract_Permission` is the custom permission.

Comment: Usinga hierarchy custom setting to allow certain users like admin/System User to change contracts

Comment: Better to create custom permission to verify the permission for the users and check for field value change.

Comment: I keep forgetting about custom permission and end up using hierarchical custom settings